Flask-SQLAlchemy. Don't create relations in second base
After the tables started being created upon server startup, there were no problems, but now I get an error with every request.

sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to
initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers.
Triggering mapper: 'Mapper[Project(projects)]'. Original exception
was: When initializing mapper Mapper[Project(projects)], expression
'task_project_relations' failed to locate a name ("name
'task_project_relations' is not defined"). If this is a class name,
consider adding this relationship() to the <class
'app.tasks.models.Project'> class after both dependent classes have
been defined.

class Task(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'to_do_base'
    __tablename__ = 'tasks'
    id = db.Column('TaskID', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column('Title', db.String(255))

class Project(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'to_do_base'
    __tablename__ = 'projects'
    id = db.Column('ProjectID', db.Integer, primary_key=True)

task_project_relations = db.Table('task_project_relations',
                                  db.Column('TaskID', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tasks.TaskID'), primary_key=True),
                                  db.Column('ProjectID', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('projects.ProjectID'), primary_key=True),
                                  bind_key='to_do_base')

Project.tasks = db.relationship('Task', secondary='task_project_relations', back_populates='projects')
Task.projects = db.relationship('Project', secondary='task_project_relations', back_populates='tasks')
    name = db.Column('ProjectName', db.String(255))

My assumption is that the relationship tables are being searched for in the wrong database, but how can this happen if there is no bind_key parameter in the relations and the location of the tables is determined automatically. I don't understand how a table can be not found if it is created when the application is created.
